# Derivation of the posterior using a non-informative prior with normal sample

Tags: normal-distribution, posterior, uninformative-prior

Consider the prior $P(\mu, \sigma^2)\propto (\sigma^2)^{-1}$. This yields the posterior
\begin{align*}
P(\mu, \Sigma^2|y) &\propto \sigma^{-n-2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_y-\mu)^2\right)\\
&\propto \sigma^{-n-2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n-1)s^2 + n(\bar y-\mu)^2]\right),
\end{align*}
where $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2$ is the sample variance of the $y_i$'s.

Can someone help me through the derivation? How is the summation of $(y_i-\mu)^2$ equal to the equation that follows? Where did $n(\bar y_i-\mu)^2$ come from?

Comment: You provided half information. Can you provide more context of the data model? What is your likelihood?

Comment: I'm looking at the derivation of the posterior distribution when data is normal and prior in non-informative (1/sigma^2). Likelihood is for normal iid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take ($y_i$-$\mu$)$^2$, subtract $\bar y$ inside the square and expand.

Comment: similar question of @Ashu Prakash
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259994/posterior-distribution-of-a-multi-parameter-model?rq=1

Comment: the important trick here is that ∑ = n x ¯